# Manually trigger mouse click in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to be able to manually trigger a mouse click and have that mouse click perform normal actions on Google maps. For instance, I would want to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "dblclick", event)` (where `event` is a normal mouse event object) and have it zoom in, as that is standard double click behavior.

Calling that exact code does trigger the doubleclick event on the map (verified by adding a listener to the map), but it does not trigger standard actions. My guess is that Google does not internally use those events for their built in actions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Example case: I want to bind the right-click to perform whatever the current double-click action is.

```
...
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", rightClick);
...

function rightClick(mouseEvent) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "dblclick", mouseEvent);
}
```

In this case I'd want a right click to zoom in when in the normal mode, to complete a polygon when in polygon draw mode, etc.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of code that shows how you are creating the `MouseEvent` and then calling `trigger`?

Comment: @SeanMickey Edited with an example. I hope that explains my problem better.

Comment: Thinking through the example you describe, I believe part of what may be happening is that when you assign your own `dblclick` listener, that is replacing the default `dblclick` listener. Have you tried the example you describe without attaching your own `dblclick` listener?

Comment: @SeanMickey Yes, but no-go. Digging through Google's obfuscated source reveals that I won't be able to trigger the required functionality, so I am going to answer and then accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google's obfuscated source for the JS library reveals that there is no way to trigger the desired functionality programmatically.